# C# How do I read / display all monitors correctly

Tags: c#, monitor

I read all monitors on a PC and it works. The problem is, that the result is like this:

> DELL P2419HDELL P2418D

I want a result like this:

> DELL P2419H, DELL P2418D

This iy my current code:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\wmi", "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorID");
foreach (ManagementObject ufn in searcher.Get())
{
    if (ufn["UserFriendlyName"] == null)
    {
        monitorModel = "No description";
    }
    else
    {
        ushort[] ufnArray = (ushort[])ufn["UserFriendlyName"];
        foreach (ushort ufnValue in ufnArray)
        {
            var ufnASCIIBytes = new byte[] { (byte)ufnValue };
            monitorModel += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ufnASCIIBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

If I write the Code like this:

```
monitorModel += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ufnASCIIBytes) + ", ";
```

the result is

> D, E, L , L, , P, 2, 4, [and so on]

Comment: Use a `List<string>` instead and then just convert it with `ToArray()` in the [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) function.

Comment: at the end of foreach,  you can try to use monitorModel +=", "  -->  Foreach(){ ... ....  ....   monitorModel +=", "; }

Answer (score -1):

Here is a method that enumerates all monitors as individual names and let's the string concatenation operation happen by callers as desired... I also noticed that there were some null characters at the ends of the strings after `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` and this removes those too.

```cs
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", EnumerateMonitors()));
}

public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateMonitors() =>
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\wmi", "SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorID").Get()
        .OfType<ManagementBaseObject>()
        .Select(mo => string.Join(
            string.Empty,
            ((ushort[])(mo["UserFriendlyName"] ?? "No description"))
                .Select(x => Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] { (byte)x }).Replace("\0", string.Empty))));
```